# Lose ability to use static keyword after assigning object as property [php]

Tags: php, oop

I don't understand why the following outputs the variable:

```
class Sample(){
    public $query;

    function __construct() {
        $test = new \SolrQuery();
        echo $test::FACET_SORT_INDEX;
        exit();
    }
}
```

But this gives me a fatal error:

> [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM,
>   expecting ',' or ';']

```
class Sample(){
    public $query;

    function __construct() {
        $this->query = new \SolrQuery();
        echo $this->query::FACET_SORT_INDEX;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the permissions on the variable?  Is there anything I can do to get around it?

Comment: You normally access constants from classes. Even `$test::FACET_SORT_INDEX` looks weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this:

```
class foo {
        static public $foo = 'foo!';
}

class bar {
        public $query;
        function t1() {
                $test = new foo();
                echo $test::foo;
        }
        function t2() {
                $this->query = new foo();
                echo $this->query::foo;
        }
        function t3() {
                echo foo::$foo;
        }
}
$x = new bar();
$x->t1();   /// dies with "undefined class constant 'foo'
$x->t2(); /// dies with unexpected  T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
$x->t3(); // works, prints "foo!"
```

Basically, you're trying to access a static class attribute using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

try `\SolrQuery::FACET_SORT_INDEX;`
that is a constant from a class not an object

Comment: It's not a "static variable" actually, but a constant